# How to implement a function to get the name string, in which the keyboard shouldnot allow the entry of special characters and numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Get the name as a string. To ensure that it contains only alphabets and white spaces, instead of checking after the entry, during the entry itself, the special characters and numbers should not be allowed.
Python 3.8.3

Answer (score 0):

One way for this is to pass your text to a function that checks if it is valid or not. An easy way is to use regEx (Python module for regular expressions) and match every combination of capital letters, lower case letters and spaces. `re.compile` creates this pattern and `re.fullmatch` checks if the whole parameter text can match this pattern.

```py
import re

def foo(your_txt):

    pattern = re.compile('[A-Za-z ]*')
    x = re.fullmatch(pattern, txt)

    if x is None:
        print("invalid")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Thank you. That serves the purpose. But is there a way that we can disable the keys other than alphabets and space? That is, if a special character or a number is entered, it shouldnot be accepted by the console.